# Problem to upload image directly from client-side to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

i am trying to upload image directly from my react-app to s3 bucket here is my code

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

//inside my component
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION
  });
  
  const S3 = new AWS.S3();
  const bucketImage = process.env.REACT_APP_S3_BUCKET_IMAGE;

//below is my function to upload image

  const onClickImage = () => {
    const imageInput = document.getElementById("imagePage");
    imageInput.click();
  };

  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    //create image object to check dimension
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    image.onload = async () => {
      // Check if the image dimensions minimum 360px x 140px
      if (image.width >= 360 && image.height >= 140) {
        // Proceed with uploading the image
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("imgBannerPage", file);
        try {
          const response = await S3.upload({
            Bucket: bucketImage,
            Key: file.name,
            Body: formData.get("imgBannerPage"),
            ACL: "public-read-write",
          }).promise();

          console.log("Image uploaded successfully:", response);
          if (response) setImage(response?.Location);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("error uploading image", err);
        }
      } else {
        // Display an alert if below 360 x 140
        Swal.fire({
          toast: true,
          position: "top-end",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3500,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          icon: "warning",
          title: "Image resolution minimum 360px X 140px",
        });
      }
    };
  };

//and below is the render
const MyPage = () => {
   const [image, setImage] = useState("")
// ...some other function

return(
<>
//....other component

 <div className="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                      <div
                        onClick={onClickImage}
                        style={{
                          width: "22.5rem",
                          height: "8.75rem",
                          border: "1px solid black",
                        }}
                        className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                      >
                        {image ? (
                          <img
                            src={image}
                            style={{
                              objectFit: "fill",
                              width: "100%",
                              height: "100%",
                            }}
                            alt=""
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <span>Choose Image</span>
                        )}
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        name=""
                        id="imagePage"
                        accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
                        onChange={uploadImage}
                        hidden
                      />
                    </div>
</>
)
};

export default MyPage;
```

and in my aws s3 i have bucket name "comeby-image" [image: bucket s3]

i try to upload files and give an error (CORS Error);
first error (https://comeby-image.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dummyImageBanner.png)[image: error image file]
second error (
https://comeby-image.s3.amazonaws.com/?max-keys=0) which i didn't understand, my goal is i am trying to upload to s3 bucket then after succeed the response is an url image like this one (https://comeby-image.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dummyImageBanner.png and i will hit my API backend to store link url image in database. How to fix it ? is there any mistakes or some step that i missed ? and Sorry for my bad english. thank